# Laravel + Voyager + Blocks - Backend Slider-Block and output

Tags: laravel, foreach, slider, block, voyager

I'm new at Laravel and I'm testing at the moment. And its actually really nice. But now I've got a problem and I don't have a clue how to solve it.

**What I did:**

1. Installed Laravel 5.7
2. [Installed Voyager](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager)
3. [Installed Voyager Frontend](https://github.com/pvtl/voyager-frontend)
4. [Installed Voyager Blocks](https://github.com/pvtl/voyager-page-blocks)

**Now i created my own Block.** I want to create an block to display an dynamic slider.

Inside my Page in my Backend it looks actually like this:
http://nimb.ws/gp1WkX

For this my Code inside the /config/page-blocks.php looks like: http://nimb.ws/XVzyCN And you can see i create 6 instances (manually) inside the slider block.

My Output inside the "dynamic_slider.blade.php" look like this: http://nimb.ws/N8ovGD and there is nothing dynamical.

**What I want to do:**

1. I want only one instance in my block. With my Image, Title, Subtitle
   and Link for my Slide. If an image is uploaded for the first slide -
   a second instance reveal and i can add a second slide. And so on...
2. I want to output my slides inside an foreach loop on my
   dynamic_slider.blade.php

I think I know how to output the loop but I cant figure out the step for my admin-block. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how I can do it?